# jquery datePicker beforeShowDay not working for 2014

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, datepicker

Hi i am trying to get jquery datePicker to get working for 2014 Year dates. it works Perfect with 2013 dates but not for 2014 date

here is my code

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var enabledDays = ['11-30-2013', '12-14-2013', '12-21-2013', '01-11-2014', '01-11-2014', '01-25-2014', '02-08-2014', '02-22-2014'];
            function enableAllTheseDays(date) {
                var m = date.getMonth(), d = date.getDate(), y = date.getFullYear();
                for (i = 0; i < enabledDays.length; i++) {
                    if ($.inArray((m + 1) + '-' + d + '-' + y, enabledDays) != -1) {
                        return [true];
                    }
                }
                return [false];
            }
            $('#datepicker').datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
                beforeShowDay: enableAllTheseDays,
                onSelect: showDate
            });
        });
    </script>

    <script>
        function showDate(date) {
            alert("Event is on " + date);
        }
    </script>
```

any solution to get this working for 2014 dates aswell..? Thanks

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/99MUJ/)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code the problem is leading zero's in the date and month for 2014.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var enabledDays = ['11-30-2013', '12-14-2013', '12-21-2013', '01-11-2014', '01-11-2014', '01-25-2014', '02-08-2014', '02-22-2014'];
        function enableAllTheseDays(date) {
            var m = date.getMonth(), d = date.getDate(), y = date.getFullYear(),mon="",day="";
            for (i = 0; i < enabledDays.length; i++) {
                m=m+1;
                mon=m.toString();
                if(mon.length <2){
                    m="0"+m;
                }
                day=d.toString();
                if(day.length <2){
                    d="0"+d;
                }
                if ($.inArray( m + '-' + d + '-' + y, enabledDays) != -1) {
                    return [true];
                }
            }
            return [false];
        }
        $('#datepicker').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
            beforeShowDay: enableAllTheseDays,
            onSelect: showDate
        });
    });
</script>

<script>
    function showDate(date) {
        alert("Event is on " + date);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Wow,,thanks for that.. working perfectly... :) Can you guide me for doing Ajax operations once i click the date, do Operations from database onSelect of date.

Comment: This is a simple ajax example using jquery where query is the variable that would be passed to the get request.
    $.ajax({url:"your.php",
  type:"GET",
  data:"query="+query,
  success: function( response ){
            alert(response)
      },
  error: function(){
       alert("Error in processing data");
      }
 );